# How to raise native error in React-Native app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, native

I am trying to test global handler for native errors (For error handling I use react-native-exception-handler).
The author of this library also created library for triggering native error for this purpose: rn-test-exception-handler.

The problem is that this library does not expose anything to JS since React-Native 0.60 (as it does not support auto-linking).

Is there a way to inject this library in my project or some other way to trigger native error so I could test global handler?

Answer (score 1):

To raise native error you could alter native modules of your dependencies.
For example, I added error throwing in **react-native-gesture-handler** file *RNGestureHandler.m*:

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    RNGestureHandlerEventExtraData *eventData = [self eventExtraData:recognizer];
    [NSException raise:@"TEST EXCEPTION" format:@"THIS IS A TEST EXCEPTION"];
    [self sendEventsInState:self.state forViewWithTag:recognizer.view.reactTag withExtraData:eventData];
}
```

To trigger error you have to use trigger some gesture.

**react-native-exception-handler** successfully catches such errors with `setNativeExceptionHandler` (though it did not catch native error I tried to insert in Clipboard module, more on this here: https://github.com/a7ul/react-native-exception-handler/issues/135)